# Отправка файлов с сайта на Google-диск

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive

ищу в интернете решение задачи, может кто может подсказать и тут. Ситуация такая, была создана гугл форма (опросник) и гуглтаблица на которую отправлялись результаты ответов на гугл форму, анкета - таблица вообщем, ничего особенного. Далее эта гугл форма была преобразована с помощью сервиса
 http://stefano.brilli.me/google-forms-html-exporter/ 
в html, далее её застилизовали красивенько и разместили на сайте кодом, всё работало и все были счастливы до тех пор.... До тех пор пока не понадобилось кроме данных пользователя отправлять ещё и файлы, тут то и проблемка получилась, гугл форма с возможностью прикрепления файла открывается только у тех пользователей у которых есть gmail, а надо что бы на опросник отвечали все, так как основная часть респондентов даже не знают что такое gmail, вообщем, может кто знает, как же можно отправить файл на гугл диск в одну из папок гугл диска при нажатии на кнопку отправки моей html анкеты?

---

https://gdriveru.blogspot.com/2015/02/FILEUPLOAD.html
Вот нашёл пример разобранный, тут на выходе получается именно то, что я хочу, но у меня не работает, данные в таблицу заносятся, а файлы в папку не попадают, изменил 2 айдишника таблицы и папки

Answer (score 2):

1. - ,-
   - ? "установить" библиотеку
   - получить и сохранить `YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN`
2. загрузить файл к себе на сайт
3. отправить его на гугл диск используя "google drive api".
   https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads
   !!! не забудь "выбрать язык" (PHP, nodejs, python, ...)